# post request using axios on Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

i am trying to post request on server by axois but unfortunately page is refreshing on button click how can i resolve this issue please  help me thanks.

**html view**

**axois script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#prospects_form").submit(function(e) {
    let url = "{{route('home.store')}}";

    var name =$("#name").val();
    var email =$("#email").val();

      axios.post(url, {
      params:{
        name: 'name',
        email:'email'
      }
      }).then((res)=>{
         console.log(res);
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });

  });
});

</script>
```

**Route**

```
 Route::post('/home/store', 'HomeController@store')->name('home.store');
```

**controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribes,email',

            ],
            [
                'name.required' => 'Name is required',
                'email.required' => 'Email is required'
            ]
        );

        $subscribes = new Subscribe();
        $subscribes = $request->name;
        $subscribes = $request->email;


        return response()->json($subscribes, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios` send data in `body` not in `params` ref link https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage

```js
axios.post(url, {
        name: 'name',
        email:'email'
      }).then((res)=>{
         console.log(res);
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });
```

`params` is used for `get` request

and to not refresh on form submit you can try

```js
$("#prospects_form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
```

and you need to `preventDefault` form action so u can submit form via ajax

### so your final code will be

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#prospects_form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let url = "{{route('home.store')}}";
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();

        axios
            .post(url, {
                name: name,
                email: email,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.preventDefault();` Like given below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#prospects_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let url = "{{route('home.store')}}";

    var name =$("#name").val();
    var email =$("#email").val();

      axios.post(url, {
      params:{
        name: 'name',
        email:'email'
      }
      }).then((res)=>{
         console.log(res);
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
      });

  });
});

</script>
```